# Scrollama, changing charts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple static webpage to accompany my research paper. While looking for solutions I stumbled upon scrollama.js. On the surface it does everything I want, but I just can't figure out how to add multiple charts (a single chart for example works since I replace the contents of the chart div). So how would one insert several simple d3 graphs into the scrollama.js demo? I'm guessing it's a javascript solution and my javascript knowledge is severely limited.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Also a jsfiddle of the demo I found while searching for any related scrollama materials: 
    https://codepen.io/bclinkinbeard/pen/OOKXjz

html

```
<section id='intro'>
  <p class='intro__overline'>
    <a href='https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/scrollama'>scrollama.js</a>
  </p>
  <h1 class='intro__hed'>Demo: Sticky Graphic</h1>
  <p class='intro__dek'>
    Start scrolling to see how it works.
  </p>
</section>
<section id='scroll'>
  <div class='scroll__graphic'>
    <div class='chart'>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='scroll__text'>
    <div class='step' data-step='1'>
      <p>STEP 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class='step' data-step='2'>
      <p>STEP 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class='step' data-step='3'>
      <p>STEP 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class='step' data-step='4'>
      <p>STEP 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id='outro'></section>
<div class='debug'></div>
```

And js

```
// using d3 for convenience
var container = d3.select("#scroll");
var graphic = container.select(".scroll__graphic");
var chart = graphic.select(".chart");
var text = container.select(".scroll__text");
var step = text.selectAll(".step");

// initialize the scrollama
var scroller = scrollama();

// generic window resize listener event
function handleResize() {
  // 1. update height of step elements
  var stepHeight = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.75);
  step.style("height", stepHeight + "px");

  // 2. update width/height of graphic element
  var bodyWidth = d3.select("body").node().offsetWidth;

  graphic
    .style("width", bodyWidth + "px")
    .style("height", window.innerHeight + "px");

  var chartMargin = 32;
  var textWidth = text.node().offsetWidth;
  var chartWidth = graphic.node().offsetWidth - textWidth - chartMargin;

  chart
    .style("width", chartWidth + "px")
    .style("height", Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 2) + "px");

  // 3. tell scrollama to update new element dimensions
  scroller.resize();
}

// scrollama event handlers
function handleStepEnter(response) {
  // response = { element, direction, index }

  // add color to current step only
  step.classed("is-active", function(d, i) {
    return i === response.index;
  });

  // update graphic based on step
  chart.select("p").text(response.index + 1);
}

function handleContainerEnter(response) {
  // response = { direction }

  // sticky the graphic (old school)
  graphic.classed("is-fixed", true);
  graphic.classed("is-bottom", false);
}

function handleContainerExit(response) {
  // response = { direction }

  // un-sticky the graphic, and pin to top/bottom of container
  graphic.classed("is-fixed", false);
  graphic.classed("is-bottom", response.direction === "down");
}

function init() {
  // 1. force a resize on load to ensure proper dimensions are sent to scrollama
  handleResize();

  // 2. setup the scroller passing options
  // this will also initialize trigger observations
  // 3. bind scrollama event handlers (this can be chained like below)
  scroller
    .setup({
      container: "#scroll",
      graphic: ".scroll__graphic",
      text: ".scroll__text",
      step: ".scroll__text .step",
      debug: true
    })
    .onStepEnter(handleStepEnter)
    .onContainerEnter(handleContainerEnter)
    .onContainerExit(handleContainerExit);

  // setup resize event
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}

// kick things off
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way is instantiate scrollama more than once:

```
    var scroller1 = scrollama();
    var scroller2 = scrollama();
```

See example here:

https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/scrollama/blob/master/dev/multiple.html